# Join in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have the following database tables: Event, User and Favorite.

An event can be favorited by many users and a user can favorite many events.

The Favorite table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE favorites
(
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    event_id INTEGER REFERENCES events(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,

    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, event_id)
);
```

What I need is a query that returns all events and information (preferably a boolean) regarding whether or not each event is favorited by a user (its ID is available and you can call it user_id).

So far I've tried:

```
Event.findAll({
    include: { 
        model: sequelize.models.favorites,
        required: false,
        where: {
            user_id: user_id
        }
    }
});
```

In the event model I have the association

```
models.events.belongsToMany(models.users, { through: 'favorites'});
```

And in the user model I have the association

```
models.users.belongsToMany(models.events, { through: 'favorites'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to come up with a solution:

```
Event.findAll({
    include: { 
        model: sequelize.models.users,
        as: 'favorite',
        where: {
            id: user_id
        },
        required: false
    }
});
```

with the following associations:

```
models.users.belongsToMany(models.events, { through: 'favorites', as: 'favorite'});

models.events.belongsToMany(models.users, { through: 'favorites', as: 'favorite'});
```